# Glyphicons are not loaded in modal (Bootstrap v3.3.6)

Tags: bootstrap-modal, glyphicons

I am facing to issue when span used in modal window is not showing the icon, even if in the main page from which I have opened the modal glyphicons are loaded properly.

```
<span class="text-success h2 glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> Login attempt:</span>
```

[image: On background glyphicons are loaded properly]

As you can see on background glyphicons are loaded properly.

Any idea what I have wrong?

Thanks, Reddy